# Vue.js newly added element not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created contenteditable like feature in my application. It works fine, I can edit and save the data but then I found out that newly added data cannot be edited using this feature. I use `obt.edited` parameter to activate edit mode. Even though I can set `obt.edited` for newly added element to TRUE but the form input don't show up. I have to refresh the page so that my contenteditable could work
Here is my vue.js code

```
getData: function(page){
    this.$http.get("obat/getObat", function(data, status, response){
    this.$set('obat', data);
  })
},
editData: function(obat){
  obat.edited = true;
  obat.namaBeforeEdit = obat.nama;
},
doneEdit: function(obat,index){
  obat.edited = false;
  this.$http.post("obat/simpanObat", obat, function(data, status, response){
    this.obat[index] = obat;
  })
},
cancelEdit: function(obat){
  obat.edited = false;
},
```

Here is my controller code where I add `edited` attribute to each data I get from database

```
public function getObat()
{
    $query = $this->obat_m->get(null,null,null);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = array(
                    'id'    => $row->id_obat,
                    'nama'  => $row->nama,
                    'harga' => $row->harga,
                    'stok'  => $row->stok,
                    'edited'=> false
                    );
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Then here is my view

```
<tbody>
              <tr v-for="obt in obat" track-by="$index">
                <td v-text="$index + 1"></td>
                <td v-if="!obt.edited">{{ obt.nama }}</td>
                <td v-if="obt.edited"><input type="text" name="editNamaObat" v-model="obt.nama"></td>
                <td v-if="!obt.edited">{{ obt.harga }}</td>
                <td v-if="obt.edited"><input type="text" name="editHargaObat" v-model="obt.harga"></td>
                <td v-if="!obt.edited">{{ obt.stok }}</td>
                <td v-if="obt.edited"><input type="text" name="editStokObat" v-model="obt.stok"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="text-center" v-if="obt.edited">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="doneEdit(obt, $index)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-hd"></i> Save Changes</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="cancelEdit(obt)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i> Cancel Editing</button>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" v-if="!obt.edited">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @click="editData(obt)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-edit"></i> Ubah</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeData(obt.nama, $index)"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-remove"></i> Hapus</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: post your vue model here

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add some verification after executing the POST call. Here you just set the variable to the object.

Second, we don't have the code that creates the data, only updates. My guess is that the object you create doesn't contain a `edited` property. To check for this property you may use [Vue DevTools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) to have direct insight to what really is in your Vue variables.

Comment: I would add verification later as I focus on the main process. And I've added my controller code where I add `edited` property. I have to refresh the page so that my editable content can work correctly.